# maximum Hamilton cycle and NP-completeness

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-complete, np

we know max tsp (maximal Hamilton cycle) is NP-Hard. is there any decision version for this problem to conclude this is NP-Complete?

Comment: The decision version is clearly NP complete, since it is NP-hard and belongs to NP (a certificate is the cycle itself). The optimization version cannot possibly be NP complete since it does not belong to NP.

Comment: The decision version of a maximization optimization problem with measure $m( \cdot )$  takes an instance $\mathcal{I}$ of the optimization problem and a number $k$ as an input, and asks to decide whether there exists a solution $S$ for $\mathcal{I}$ such that $m(S) \ge k$.

Comment: Exactly as in my previous comment? Given an instance (graph) $G$ of the problem and the value $k$, decide whether there exists a Hamiltonian cycle $C$ in $G$ such that the weight of $C$ is at least $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decision problem is NP-complete iff it is in NP and it is NP-hard.

The decision version of Max-Hamiltonian cycle would be "given a weighted graph $G$ and a value k, decide whether there exists a Hamiltonian cycle of weight at least $k$ in $G$".

Your problem is clearly in NP (since a yes-certificate is the sought Hamiltonian cycle). Moreover it is also NP-hard since it is a generalization of the classical Hamiltonian cycle problem on unweighted graphs (simply set all edge weights to $1$ and $k=n$ to obtain an instance of your problem).

We can then conclude that this problem is NP-complete.